# Is Google Colab has malware?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-cloud-platform, google-colaboratory

I have been a avid user of Google Colab for the past 6months. It's been my tool of choice for Deep learning model training. But this day morning, I was training a pretrained model with transfer learning in Colab, suddenly I found my data cap is exhausted. It revoked a suspicion in me, I tried looking in the network stat and found 1.3Gb has been used in Upload Bandwidth. But I didn't have anything running in the background. Later today, I extended my data cap and started training again, this time I found while traing in colab sucking my upload bandwidth too much.

Is there any malicious code in colab?

Framework : Tensorflow
Library API : Keras
Pretrained Model : ResNet152v2 (imported using keras API)
Dataset : Bird Species-180 Dataset (downloaded using Kaggle API)

[Screenshot of Colab utilizing my upload bandwidth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wySq.png)

Comment: This isn't intentional; if you can repro this: (1) please `Help` -> `Send feedback` mentioning this SO question, and (2) try in an incognito window.

Answer (score 1):

You're running your code on browser so yes colab will take some data from you, completely depends on the notebook you're running. The code you run on your browser doesn't magically goes to colab, and I see very low bandwidth usage in the screenshot (in range of kilobytes) which is nothing unusual.

I don't think they have malware, specifically not for colab. Yes, google takes some data from your chrome but it has hardly anything to do with being malicious.